# How to hide root view until it's ready for input?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm adding a layout in `OnCreate` like this...

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

There's an unsightly pause between it first appearing and when it's ready to receive user input. During this period, it also covers the background, which it a loading scene.

Thus, how can I set the layout and it's controls to be invisible until it's finished building?

I've tried this...

```
var root = FindViewById<Layout>(Resource.Layout.Main);

root.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
```

... but root is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The   `Main` layout has its root view, you could control this view to realize your idea.
In XML:

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">  //Initial status 

   .......
```

And use jave code:

```
    ConstraintLayout root = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
    root.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: That's basically what I've tried, although I have a LinearLayout, which doesn't have a setVisibility method.

Comment: LinearLayout definitely has setVisibility method. Please check whether the LinearLayout variable is null? set breakpoint and debug it

Comment: Oh, in Xamarin it's `root.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Invisible`.

Comment: .. and yes it's null anyhow.